# Historical Data Comparison in realtime - faster in SQL or code?

Tags: performance, azure, azure-storage, azure-sql-database

I have a requirement in the project I am currently working on to compare the most recent version of a record with the previous historical record to detect changes.

I am using the Azure Offline data sync framework to transfer data from a client device to the server which causes records in the synced table to update based on user changes.  I then have a trigger copying each update into a history table and a SQL query which runs when building a list of changes to compare the current record vs the most recent historical by doing column comparisons - mainly string but some integer and date values.

Is this the most efficient way of achieving this?  Would it be quicker to load the data into memory and perform a code based comparison with rules?

Also, if I continually store all the historical data in a SQL table, will this affect the performance over time and would I be better storing this data in something like Azure Table Storage?  I am also thinking along the lines of cost as SQL usage is much more expensive that Table Storage but obviously I cannot use a trigger and would need to insert each synced row into Table Storage manually.

Comment: Have you benchmarked the two approaches to see which ones faster with your data?

Comment: Not yet, but that of course is the next step!  Was just looking for some general advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sync framework I am using deals with the actual data changes, so i only get new history records when there is an actual change. Given a batch of updates to a number of records, i need to compare all the changes with their previous state and produce an output list of whats changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid querying and comparing the historical data altogether, because the most recent version is already in the main table (and if it's not, it will certainly be new/changed data).

Consider a main table with 50.000 records and 1.000.000 records of historical data (and growing every day).

Instead of updating the main table directly and then querying the 1.000.000 records (and extracting the most recent record), you could query the smaller main table for that one record (probably an ID), compare the fields, and only if there is a change (or no data yet) update those fields and add the record to the historical data (or use a trigger / stored procedure for that).

That way you don't even need a database (probably containing multiple indexes) for the historical data, you could even store it in a flat file if you wanted, depending on what you want to do with that data.

Comment: The sync framework I am using deals with the actual data changes, so i only get new history records when there is an actual change.  Given a batch of updates to a number of records, i need to compare all the changes with their previous state and produce an output list of whats changed.